# Declaration of std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> results in a crash

Tags: c++, eigen

I had asked this question a while back where the following declaration results in a run time crash on W7 machine.

```
std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> inv_K_mat2(42, Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(4, 5));
```

However now I am seeing this on a Win10 machine also and wondering if I can get some help figuring this out. Since Win10 is a supported platform I need to somehow address this issue. Running through the debugger I see the application crashing exactly at the above line. Other declarations such as

```
Eigen::MatrixXd BMat(3,10);
```

are working. I can't determine why the above declaration is failing on some machine architecture. May be it is due to the mixing of stl containers with Eigen or missing run time libraries? Is there another way to specify the above declaration. Any help to fix this problem is very much appreciated

Comment: AFAIR, `Eigen` objects may require specific alignment (due to the aggressive optimization attempts which might be enabled). Googling this, I found immediately a note in the doc. FYI: [Using STL Containers with Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html): _A 16-byte-aligned allocator must be used. Eigen does provide one ready for use: aligned_allocator._ _If you want to use the std::vector container, you need to #include <Eigen/StdVector>._ (I must admit I'm no expert - just one who is having an eye on this from time to time.)

Comment: I do have that include declaration in my code

Comment: ...and btw. I overlooked _For other Eigen types, such as Vector3f or **MatrixXd**, no special care is needed when using STL containers._ :-(

Comment: @pk68 `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> inv_K_mat2(42, Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(4, 5));` -- Have you looked at the call stack to determine what series of functions leads to the crash?  A `std::vector` should be able to handle any type that has the proper move and copy semantics with the given allocator type.  Are you sure the error isn't a memory corruption bug, and you're assuming the issue is with the declaration?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. I don't think it is memory corruption. It is when the execution hits this declaration the program crashes. Should I not have <Eigen/StdVector> declaration when using std stl containers?

Comment: @pk68 If it's not memory corruption, then you should be able to create a one-line `main` program that only has that vector declaration (turn optimizations off, to ensure the compiler doesn't wipe away the line).  If a one-line program has no issues, then the issue is pointing towards memory corruption, and not an issue with `std::vector` or Eigen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the suggestion. I will give that a try.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I found the cause of the issue. I was compiling with /arch:AVX2 option which seems to be cause of the crash on some machines. I guess the CPU of machine where the program crashes doesn't support AVX2. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is an Wikipedia article about AVX which lists the [CPUs with AVX2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX2)

Comment: You need to provide a [mre], make sure that all compilation units are compiled with the same options (at least regarding target architecture), and of course that the CPU actually supports that instruction set.